# Create a variable out of a tuple's tuple?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm working out of a Django framework and I'm trying to generate a list of li's. The only problem is that each li that is generated contains all of the corresponding values, rather than just the instance that they appear in sequentially. For example:

If I were to print `name` in the example below, it would give me:

"Exxon Mobil Corp.International Business Machines Corp.

How can I get it so that it would print "Exxon Mobil Corp." when called on the first time and "International Business Machines Corp." when called on the second time?

```
tuple = (('Exxon Mobil Corp.', 'XOM', '102.59', '-0.06'), ('International Business Machines Corp.', 'IBM', '182.56', '0.00'))

name, symbol, last, diff = zip(*tuple)
```

Here's my code though. This is in my views file:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT `name`,`symbol`,`last`,`diff` FROM `ticker_nyse100` LIMIT 5,1")
data = c.fetchall()
name, symbol, last, diff = zip(*data)
```

This is in the base html file:

```
{% for each in data %}
  <li class = "tkr_name">
    <span class = "comp_info">{{ name }} [{{ symbol }}] </span>{{ last }} 
    {% if '+' in diff %}
      <span class = "up">&#9650;</span> {{ diff }}</li>
    {% elif '-' in diff %}
      <span class = "down">&#9660;</span> {{ diff }}</li>
    {% else %}
      <span class = "flat">-</span> {{ diff }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I fixed it now. Sorry abut that.

Comment: There is nothing Django-1.6 specific about your post; please leave the tags as I updated them, if you want the maximum exposure from people that might be able to answer.

Comment: Are you saying you are getting `Exxon Mobil Corp.International Business Machines Corp.` followed by `[some symbol]` with each `<span>` tag in the output? `data` in the template is *just* `data` from the `c.fetchall()` result?

Comment: I was thinking for each tuple inside of the tuple in `data` it would create an li, which it does and yes the `data` is just the `data` from the `c.fetchall()` result.

Comment: For the li's themselves, it prints out all the names then all the symbols lasts and diffs along with any span tags.

Comment: Yes, I see now what you are doing; Anentropic has it in one. You split out the different columns into new lists, and for each iteration over `data` you are ignoring the row, and interpolating those column lists instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are doing this, to create four lists:

```
name, symbol, last, diff = zip(*data)
```

But then in the template you don't iterate over them properly. It would be simpler to get rid of the zip line and just do this in the template:

```
{% for name, symbol, last, diff in data %}
```